# Insert/Update/Delete rows to an existing table by checking the received data in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2017

I have an employee transactional table with millions of records. I have a requirement to check the newly arrived data to verify any change in the existing record for same employee. If there is a change then update the existing data. If it's not present then delete the existing record. If its new insert it. If no change keep as it is.

I have implemented this with checksum-based approach, however, its quite time consuming. I am not preferring `MERGE` based approach due to performance constraints. Is there is any other built-in function based approach can suggest?

Comment: WHich Performance constraints are you talking about? If you have the data complete as a whole resultset, it is consistent as well as it uses an implicit transaction.

Comment: Show us what the *actual* queries you have are. ARe you doing something like `WHERE CHECKSUM(CONCAT(Src.Col1,Src.Col2,Src.Col3)) <> CHECKSUM(CONCAT(trg.Col1,trg.Col2,trg.Col3))`? That won't be SARGable.

Comment: I have same employee transaction table in 2 databases for reporting purpose. I need to perform INSERT/UPDATE/DELETE/NO ACTION to the reporting table based on the transaction table data. I am loading the transaction data to a temp table along with check sum and an operation flag column (I - insert, O- Overwrite, D- Delete, N- No operation). Later the reporting table will be updated. The stored procedure is taking more than 1 hour to complete. That's why I trying some other option.

Comment: I don't think you are going to get any actionable answers without sample data and your existing code. An execution plan might help as well. 1 hour is excessive so showing your code is key.